# Python subprocess.check_call issue

Tags: python, subprocess

I know I'm doing something wrong.

In the shell i would type:

```
cuebreakpoints cuefile.cue | shnsplit -o flac flacfile.flac
```

This would then split the flac file according to the cuefile. Since I'm in the process of writing a small help tool (in Python) to convert flac files I obviously wanted to incorporate this bit in my code.

So in a pythonic way I wrote:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(args):
    ...
    cmd = ('cuebreakpoints', cue, '|', 'shnsplit', '-o', 'flac', flacs[0])
    subprocess.check_call(cmd, cwd=None)
    ....
```

'cue' being the cuefile and 'flacs[0]' being the flac file. However I get a:

> subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '('cuebreakpoints', '41_30sec.cue', '|', 'shnsplit', '-o', 'flac', '41_30sec.flac')' returned non-zero exit status 1

Is there a problem because of the PIPE ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to passing the command string to a shell (and skip the security problems pointed out by larsmans), you can create two `subprocess.Popen` objects and connect the output of the first one to the input of the second one (that's basically what the shell will do for you):

For an example about how to do that, please have a look at the [replacing shell pipeline](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline) section in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use shell features such as pipes, you need to give `check_call` a `shell=True` kwarg and give the command as a single string:

```
check_call("cuebreakpoints '%s' | shnsplit -o flac '%s'" % (cue, flacs[0]),
           shell=True)
```

But note that `shell=True` is a [potential security hazard](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) when used with unsanitized `cue` or `flacs`.

Comment: Thanks, since i would like to not use shell=True I would go with jcollado's answer. Of course you are both correct so Thanks again

Comment: @wagner-felix: if you drop the `'` that I put in the answer, then `pipes.quote` should be enough for filename sanitization. +1 for jcollado, though.

Answer (score 0):

A little sidenote here.

When writing python scripts using subcommand, I find shlex really helpful to parse more complex commands without worrying too much about how the list will look.

```
import shlex

...
cmd = "cuebreakpoints '%s' | shnsplit -o flac '%s'" % (cue, flacs[0])
args = shlex.split(cmd)

subprocess.call(args ...)
```